# Webcrawler running in background - Use real time spring batch app to deal with information grabbed

Tags: java, web-crawler, spring-batch, batch-processing

I want to create a spring batch application. 
The skelethon is like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CrawlerBatchConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step step) {
        return jobs.get("myJob").start(step).build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step(StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Product, Product>chunk(11)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    protected Step runCrawlerStep (StepBuilderFactory steps){
        return steps.get("runCrawlerStep").tasklet(tasklet()).build();
    }

    private Tasklet tasklet() {
        return new RunCrawlerTasklet();
    }


    public ItemProcessor<Product, Product> processor() {
        return new ItemProcessor<Product, Product>() {
            @Override
            public Product process(Product product) throws Exception {
                return new Product();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Product> reader() {
        return new ProductItemReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Product> writer() {
        return new ItemWriter<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends Product> list) throws Exception {
                list.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So I have this product class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_produtos")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    public Product() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FABRICANTE")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    @Embedded
    private Ean13 ean;

    @Transient
    private Keywords keywords;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setEan(Ean13 ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Keywords getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(Keywords keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }    
}
```

That holds information that is extracted by a web crawler program. This crawler is a class that run in background to extract all product from a website. When a product is extracted, it fire an event that can be captured by listeners.

The crawler life cycle and the batch is finite, when all product is extract, the app can stop. But the process of grab and store (by batch) is asynchronous.

As I said, I have to create a batch program that should start this crawler (step1) and listen to this crawler to read data from it, process the data and write in a database (step2).

I worked a bit with spring batch, but not very solid way, I'm
struggling to mount this batch. More precisely in knowing how to make the crawler running in the background and as he gathers information, run the process of reading, processing  and writing of the batch.

Comment: Given the real time nature and the lack of a finite amount of data to be processed, why batch and not integration?  What is batch giving you for this solution?

Comment: It's not so realtime. Realtime here means asynchronous. Realtime is not the main subject, actually I left misconception in the question I will edit... There will not be so much realtime data, but asynchronous data, since the crawler will take x time to grab all products, and in so far as the product is extract, it will be store in database.